# auto delete disabled AD accounts after xx day

Tags: active-directory, domain, scheduled-task

I'm looking for an app that can run to auto delete disabled AD user accounts in a specific OU after say 30 days

Any advice will be highly appreciated

Comment: I am sure this could be accomplished using powershell. Did you want an app specificlly?

Answer (score 1):

Use PowerShell. Look into the commands `Search-ADAccount`, `Get-ADuser`, `Remove-AdUser`